# как можно получить результат уравнения "12 + 7" если это строка?

Tags: javascript, преобразование-типов

// пробовал все и Number() , ParseInt() +унарный плюс

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, с которым у вас возникли сложности

Comment: `eval("12 + 7")` не?

Comment: [Never use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: https://ericsmekens.github.io/jsep/ . Любой рукописный код разбирающий выражения лучше чем `eval`. Если вам интересна тема, то можно написать "строчный калькулятор" самому. Хорошее и интересное упражнение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy шикарно. Создать функцию ещё в 2014-ом, потом объявить его опасной и запретить использование это по Java Script-ски. [Вспомнил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fp7c.png).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```js
console.log('12 + 7'.split('+').reduce((sum, num) => sum + +num, 0));
```